# why are the default `ulimit` values so low

Tags: memory, stack, ulimit

today with many GBs of memory available, why are the default `ulimits` set so low ? For example, the stack size on my machine (Debian Buster) is only 8192

```
ulimit -s
8192
```

I am not aware that this is causing any issues, but I am just curious why it is so low.

If there is plenty of memory available, would increasing this limit to lets say 1GB have any benefits ?

Or perhaps is lower limit beneficial, as it prevents mis-behaved or mis-configured runaway programs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8,192 kilobytes is 8 megabytes. That's a very reasonable limit on the size of a process's stack. I don't see any particular benefit to raising it. I can't think of a program that would need that much stack space.

I know that many development tools build (or did, a few years back) programs with a default stack size of 1 megabyte, and I haven't heard anybody complain that their stack is too small.